# livro black hat go / variavel nao usada no golang

Tags: golang

```
func foo(i interface{}) {
switch v := i.(type) {
case int:
fmt.Println("I'm an integer!")
case string:
fmt.Println("I'm a string!")
default:
fmt.Println("Unknown type!")
}
}
```

pesquisei sobre essa estrutura de controle,mas como essa linguagem eh nova eu nao acho muita coisa no nosso idioma,minha compreensao do ingles nao eh das melhores.
peguei do livro "black hat go" e esse codigo nao esta funcionando,alguem poderia me dizer o motivo? e como fazer funcionar?

logs do compilador(1.13):

```
# command-line-arguments
./hw.go:6:9: v declared and not used
```

Answer (score 3):

É exatamente o que o erro diz.

Enquanto algumas linguagens mostram um alerta quando você declara uma variável mas não a utiliza, Go te dá um erro de compilação. Essa é uma característica da linguagem que já foi bastante questionada, mas os criadores são bastante resilientes quanto a essa decisão, e parece que nada vai mudar por enquanto.

Também não tem como passar um parâmetro para o compilador para desligar essa analise de variáveis, então o jeito é arrumar o código e remover variáveis não utilizadas:

```
func foo(i interface{}) {
  switch i.(type) {
  case int:
    fmt.Println("I'm an integer!")
  case string:
    fmt.Println("I'm a string!")
  default:
    fmt.Println("Unknown type!")
  }
}
```

Outra estratégia que pode ser útil enquanto você está depurando o programa é atribuir o valor de uma variável não utilizada para `_`. Esse símbolo basicamente descarta qualquer valor atribuído a ele, e o compilador não reclama quando você está sendo explicito a respeito de um valor que não está sendo utilizado.